# Form Redirect Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm working on an HTML app in which there is a form. On clicking the submit button, I make a server-side call using `jquery.ajax()`. However, whenever an exception is returned from the server, like a `Status Code 500`, I need to display an error message on the same page. However, it automatically redirects when it encounters an error. I tried using the `statusCode` setting in jquery.ajax() like this:

```
$.ajax(
{
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'my url',
    //...
    successCode: {
        500: function(response) {
            alert(response.getResponseHeader("xyz"));
            $('some_selector').show();
        }
    },
    success: function(){},
    error: function(){}
    //...
})
```

But this does not seem to work. It redirects me to the action link and displays the JSON error and I cannot think of a way to prevent this redirect. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your ajax options are outside of the ajax call put your parameters inside like 

 `$.ajax(){options}`  =>  `$.ajax({options})`

Try this,

```
    $.ajax({url: 'your url',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (response) {
            //succesfull request

        }
    }).fail(function (response) {
        //failed request
    });
```

You should be able to find the status code in the fail using `response.status`

I think your submit button is triggering the redirect. Try adding

```
$("#myform").submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();  
});
```

to prevent the redirect

Comment: sorry it was within the call, I put it the wrong way here.
event.preventDefault isn't working
also, the code does not enter the success function for server-side errors

Comment: No it enters the fail function because the request failed with a server side error.